# Debian 9 does not load login screen

Tags: debian, services, disk, btrfs, accounts

My HP laptop fails to load the login screen after saying

> [FAILED] Failed to start Accounts Service

There's an error concerning the partition of a disk that keeps showing up.

> BTRFS critical (device sda3): corrupt node: root=5 .........

When I launch the terminal on non graphical mode and try to type `apt-get update` for instance, it does not recognize the command and also keeps display

> BTRFS critical (device sda3): corrupt node: root=5 .........

Running `systemctl status accounts-daemon.service`

> Active: failed
>   code=exited,status=127

Anyone knows how to fix this and whether there's a workaround this?

Comment: You need to correct the file system and lookout for physical drive errors.

Comment: How to correct the file system?

Comment: Yes, that should be your question. Unfortunately I know nothing about BTRFS.

Comment: What is the complete BTRFS error message?